# Filter Django Models using lists of field parameters

Tags: django, filter, model, keyword-argument

I'd like to be able to pass any number of fields and values into a function to identify relevant rows:

`models.py`

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'Ronaldo')
    defender = BooleanField(default = False)
    midfielder = BooleanField(default = False)
    attacker = BooleanField(default = False)
    goalkeeper = BooleanField(default = False)
```

`views.py`

```
def find_player(**kwargs):#to be used in some view
    players = Player.objects.filters(kwargs).all()
    for player in players:
        #do something with player...

find_player({defender:True, goalkeeper:True})#selects rows with players who defend and play in goal
find_player({defender:True, attacker:False})#...
find_player({defender:False})
```

What I'm trying to do above clearly doesn't work! I know that I could also use exec() to get what I want:

```
def find_player(string_of_params):
    players = exec(Player.objects.filters(string_of_params).all())
    for player in players:
        print(player)

find_player('defender=True, goalkeeper=True')#prints rows with players who can defend and go in goal
find_player('defender=True, attacker=False')#...
find_player('defender=False'})
```

But I think there has to be a more natural way of unpacking the contents of a dictionary directly into `filter()`.

Any guidance on this welcome.

Comment: Use ** to unpack a dictionary into keyword arguments: `players = Player.objects.filter(** kwargs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *unpack* the dictionary in the function so `**kwargs` instead of `kwargs`:

```
#               ↓ no double asterisk
def find_player(kwargs):
    #                                ↓↓ double asterisk
    players = Player.objects.filters(**kwargs).all()
    # …
```

Then you can use this by passing a dictionary:

```
find_player({defender:True, goalkeeper:True})
find_player({defender:True, attacker:False})
find_player({defender:False})
```

Comment: Many thanks. That was exactly what  I wasn't getting.